# Creating and writing a file C++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, scripting, hex, writetofile

I have made a scripting language and I was writing a program which would 1: Ask for your path to read the script and 2: Compile the code into a custom Hexadecimal which would be read by another program to do the hard work for me. My problem is I cannot create a new file and write the custom hexadecimal code onto that file.

Here is an example of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wincon.h>
#include <fstream>;
using namespace std;

int main(){
string path;
string title;
cout << "Enter your path to compile your *.egSCRIPT file: ";
cin >> path;
cout << "Enter the title for the new file";
cin >> title;

ofstream myfile(path+"\\"+title+".myScriptLanguage");
myfile.open(path);
myfile << "IT WORKS!!!";
myfile.close();
return 0;
}
```

I want it to make a new .whatevertheheckyouwanttocallit file and write onto the file IT WORKS!!! just as a sample. I will eventually write onto it a custom hexadecimal system of code to be read by my interpreter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error do you see, concretely?

Comment: I have no errors. Just for a test I will write the path and it 'should' make a .whateveryouwanttocallit file and write onto it IT WORKS!!!.

Comment: And what's your actual result?? I don't get your question ...

Comment: Nothing is my result. What I want to do is create a file and write text onto that file saying "IT WORKS!!!". What I will eventually do, though, is implement my own custom Hexadecimal code to be interpreted by another program I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open(path+"\\"+title+".myScriptLanguage");
myfile << "IT WORKS!!!";
myfile.close();
```

Try the above;

Comment: I found my problem. It is the path itself. When I write the path, I have a space, so I am actually starting a new input and not getting the whole path because it is divided into two sections.